# AngularJS variables based on other int variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, scope, data-modeling

extremely new developer here.
Trying to make an expenses calculator in which the sum of inputted integers from a table (each of which have a specific default value) become the int value of another variable. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

The javascript/angular below

```
var app = angular.module('expenses', []);
app.controller('mainCtrlr', function($scope) {
    var expenseTotal<----variable I cannot get to work

    var expenseOne;
    var expenseTwo;
    var expenseThree;

    $scope.expenseOne = 270;
    $scope.expenseTwo = 265;
    $scope.expenseThree= 65;
});
```

populates the data of this table

```
<div ng-app="expenses" ng-controller="mainCtrlr">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td> Expense </td><td><input type= int ng-model="expenseOne"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Other Expense </td><td><input type=int ng-model= "expenseTwo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Third Expense </td><td><input type=int ng-model= "expenseThree"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
Total {{expenseTotal}}
</div>
```

I can't get {{expenseTotal}} to show anything other than NaN.  I'd like it to be a usable variable that will factor into other equations, but be based on the sum of the expenses.  Does anyone know what else needs to be in my javascript file to make this work?

thanks in advance and I'm sorry if it's been asked before but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the variable in the code?

Comment: I am, but in other parts of the code.. i just isolated where the issue was to avoid clutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('expenses', [])
    .controller('mainCtrlr', function($scope) {
        $scope.expenseOne = 270;
        $scope.expenseTwo = 265;
        $scope.expenseThree = 65;
        $scope.expenseTotal = $scope.expenseOne + $scope.expenseTwo + $scope.expenseThree;
    });
```

var declarations are not automatically added to the scope, so if you want them available in your view, using brackets, you need to define them in your controller, as properties of the $scope variable.

Comment: This is great thank you.  Is there an easy way, branching off of this solution to keep {{expenseTotal}} live updating as I change what is in the input? If I include {{expenseOne}} in the HTML it live updates as I change what is in the form.  If this isn't possible, would you suggest that I use a timer to have it refresh every few seconds or so? or is there a better way to make it seemingly 'dynamically update'

Comment: It will update automatically, as long as the calculation used to define the variable lives in the angular digest cycle. If not, there is the $scope.$apply() method, if you are say using a function outside the digest cycle to set the value for that property.  Here is a pretty good article about using $apply: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html

Comment: I must confess I've spent the last hour trying to understand and did research, but am having trouble making it work.  I can't seem to figure out what method to use to get the expression to reset.  I can get it to work when I do things like count changes (using 'counter++') as the update to make, is it a return statement of some sort? i'm basically just trying to make it refresh based on the other values.

Comment: I really can't help further unless I was to see your actual code. I don't think your approach in counting changes or looking for a return statement is the right approach, scope variables are automatically updated in the view when they are changed in the 'angular realm'. I think you should try to understand angular scope better by reading the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope 
Like I said, it's hard to address the specific problem you're encountering without seeing your code base.

Answer (score 1):

The `{{expenseTotal}}` refferes to `$scope.expenseTotal`, so you can either set it in your controller:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.expenseTotal = 4; // Do your calculations here
});
```

Or you can reference the controller in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    Total {{ctrl.expenseTotal}}
</div>
```

---

If you want the three variables added up you can just write:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    ...
    Total {{expenseOne + expenseTwo + expenseThree}}
</div>
```

In that case there is no need for a total variable.